# Query for Offset Rolling Sum & Count - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been working to build a distinct count and sum total of sales based on orders placed 4 to 180 days back for each day in the data table starting at Orders placed on day 181, then grouped by Month & Year, but have been unable to do it.

The end result would look something like the table below. Each order would show up multiple times, up to 176 times, but would be distinct for the given day (order 42999, placed on 10-01-2011 for example would be counted once on every day between 10-05-2011 and 2-01-2012 for example)

```
| OrdMonthYr |   Grouped Order Count | Sum of Orders |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2011-06    |       140             |     $450      |
| 2011-07    |       190             |     $500      |
| 2011-08    |       250             |     $600      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

The order count would take the total count of sales for a given day executed 4 to 180 days prior to that day (so March 1st, 2011 would have a  distinct order count and order sum for orders placed between Nov 1st, 2010 and Feb 25th, 2011 as an example) followed by a function aggregating each of those totals up to month & year per the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to get cumulative sum and count for the previous days from 4 to 180. But its not clear how it should be rolled up
If so you may use analytic functions. Next query will calculate it

```
select trunc(o.orderdate)
      ,count(*) over (order by trunc(o.orderdate) range between 180 PRECEDING AND 4 PRECEDING )
      ,sum(amount) over (order by trunc(o.orderdate) range between 180 PRECEDING AND 4 PRECEDING)
    from orders o
```

What about rolling up orders to month. May be you need to take the first of every month and get sum and amount if so you may just take one row for each month from previous query:

```
select ord_date, cnt,sum_amount FRoM (
select trunc(o.orderdate) as ord_date
      ,count(*) over (order by trunc(o.orderdate) range between 180 PRECEDING AND 4 PRECEDING ) as cnt
      ,sum(amount) over (order by trunc(o.orderdate) range between 180 PRECEDING AND 4 PRECEDING) as sum_amount
      ,row_number() over (order by trunc(o.orderdate),rowid) as RN
    from orders o)
 WHERE rn = 1 
   and ord_date = trunc(ord_date,'MM')
```

Comment: I want to roll the daily counts of orders from 4 to 180 days prior by month and year.

Comment: Its not clear yet, for example we take a January of 2016 which  orders we should take in account? From 05-jul-2015 up to 28-dec-2016 or we should take all orders from 05-jul-2015 up to 28-dec-2016 for 01-jan-2016 + all orders from 06-jul-2015 up to 29-dec-2016 for 02-jan-2016 ... to 31-jan-2016?

Comment: We would take 05-jul-2015 through 28-dec-2016 for just march 1st. March 2nd would be 06-jul-2015 through 29-dec-2016 and so on for the whole month of march. Then we would aggregate up the totals for each day by month

Comment: Well you may wrap my first query and `group by trunc(ord_date,'MM')`. But in that case you will take some orders up to 31 times

Comment: Yep, it's looking at total potential orders based on orders placed by customers in that window

Answer (score 0):

Does this get at what you want?

```
select orderdate,
       (select count(*)
        from orders o
        where o.orderdate between d.dte - 180 an d.dte - 4
       ) as cnt,
       (select sum(amount)
        from orders o
        where o.orderdate between d.dte - 180 an d.dte - 4
       ) as amount
from (select distinct orderdate as dte from orders) d;
```

Comment: the range needs to be 4 to 180 days back, so would it be (d.dte - 4) and (d-dte - 180) ?

Comment: @Danimov82 . . . Ahh, now I see how that fits in.

Comment: So would count and sum be count of order ID and sum of order amounts I assume

Comment: @Danimov82 . . . Yes.

Comment: Thanks - swapping out your variable for orderdate right after select with mine, I'm getting an invalid identifier error (specifying both the DB & order table). Not seeing anything in your query that could cause that, any thoughts as to what it could be from? Not sure if it has to do with the sub query after FROM or not...

Comment: Looks like the first "orderdate" falls outside of the FROM query, which is why it's being flagged as invalid. How else could I pull the date as I'd like to to sort / group by Month and Year given the structure of the FROM query?